# NullPointerException from fragment function when trying to update a textView from the main

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to create an app that lists cities in one fragment and when clicked, print a short description in another fragment.

Here is the description class with the updateDescription function:

```
public class Description extends Fragment {

public Description() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.description_fragment   , container, false);
}

public void updateDescription(String text){
    TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_to_be_updated);
    textView.setText(text);

}

}
```

And here is the .xml file for that class:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/des_layout"
tools:context="com.example.connormclean.lab3.Description">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="146dp"
    android:id="@+id/text_to_be_updated"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/frag_test"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

This is causing this error:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.connormclean.lab3, PID: 3903
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.connormclean.lab3.Description.updateDescription(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.connormclean.lab3.MainActivity.sendText(MainActivity.java:47)
                  at com.example.connormclean.lab3.City_list.getDescription(City_list.java:91)
                  at com.example.connormclean.lab3.City_list$1.onItemClick(City_list.java:46)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to show us `City_list` and `MainActivity`. Please [edit] the question

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pointed to by this line in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.connormclean.lab3.Description.updateDescription(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.example.connormclean.lab3.MainActivity.sendText(MainActivity.java:47)
```

The mistake is on line 47 of `MainActivity`, which you did not include in your question. The object on which you are invoking `updateDescription()` is null. Look for the problem there. You probably forgot to initialize it properly.

Answer (score 0):

From where you are calling updateDescription(String text) method, call it once the view is created. If you call it before the view is created then you will get NullPointerException.